# Is this an acceptable way of mapping Dispatch to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In React using Redux I had previously been mapping disptach to props in the following way

an action creator file with the actions in exported like this

```
export const anActionCreator = data =>{ return function(dispatch){
dispatch({type:"THE_ACTION",payload:data})
}}
```

then importing like this

```
import {anActionCreator} from "../store/actions"
```

mapping them to props like this

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch, payload) {
return {
anActionCreator: payload => {
  dispatch(anActionCreator(payload));
}
};
}
```

Its cumbersome and time consuming, so i switched to this

action creator file

```
const anActionCreator = data =>{ return function(dispatch){
dispatch({type:"THE_ACTION",payload:data})
}}

module.exports{anActionCreator}
```

(there would of course be more than one action creator)

importing them like this

```
import actionCreators from "../store/actions
```

mapping them to props like this

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch, payload) {
const keys = Object.keys(actionCreators);
var obj = {};
keys.forEach(key => {
 obj[key] = payload => {
   dispatch(actionCreators[key](payload));
 };
});
return obj;
}
```

Is there any reason why this is bad practise? Or is there a much better way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have roughly implemented [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators).

Your code could look something like this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import * as actionCreators from "../store/action

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}
```

With `react-redux`, it can do this for you automatically if you pass an *object*, so you should be able to do something like:

```
import * as actionCreators from "../store/action

const mapDispatchToProps = actionCreators;

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Here's the source in `react-redux` that does this all for you: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/0c048f0646754de103cc2d9825762340bed06119/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L16-L22 *(this will only work assuming you only need to bind dispatch to all of these action creators and nothing else)*

Comment: I switched to using the bindActionCreators method(thanks for the advice), but now I cannot use the spread operator in an action,if I do i get an import error, which says there is no default export.

Comment: Can you provide a Codesandbox example?